# How to make bootstrap navbar dropdown with list item badges aligned to the right?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In the documentation for [badges](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#badges), the badge is nested under a `nav nav-pills nav-stacked` class.

But I have a dropdown menu in a navbar that uses badges. I think it's because it's in a `.navbar` or a `.dropdown-menu` or a '.nav-tabs' that when I apply `.pull-right` to the badge, it wraps to a new line, which I don't want.

Has anyone had luck incorporating dropdown menus and getting badges to the right to the right? (take that, Beyonce song)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You align the badge right just as you would any element, for example we can use `float:right`. In the example that the Bootstrap website gave, the badges are in a `<span>` element. But we don't have to do that, for example we can add it in a `<div>`, then right-align that `<div>`. For example:

```
<div style="float:right" class="badge">42</div>
```

The dropdown menu could look something like this, for example:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">
        <div style="float:left">Stuff</div>
        <div style="float:right" class="badge">42</div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Hello World</a></li>
</ul>
```

**[Here is a Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8198/)**

Comment: In the fiddle, the badge is also going to a new line, or at least adding more height to the `li`

Comment: Oh it is in some browsers ( it's on the same line in Chrome). I'll fix that.

Comment: You have a fix for it in firefox? I couldn't find the css rules in the inspector. I suspect it may be happening in javascript. A bit of knowledge transfer saves so much time. Thank you so much. I'll look for the updated fiddle soon.

Comment: Thanks so much! I ended up not needing the `clear: both;` line. It still wrapped and displayed messed up regardless of it. I instead set a min-width to the `ul` element. I suppose keeping the `clear: both;` div  is useful if you want to put more content in each link without ruining the formatting.

Comment: As a sidenote, it seems bootstrap seems to prioritize `.label-primary` as being more right compared to `.label-default` for some reason. (I was trying labels as well as badges)

Comment: This only works for short labels, after some symbols the badge still drops to a new line...