# Add badge (get cart contents count) in bootstrap navbar

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Before I ask, a little overview of my project. I'm working in a e-commerce using wordpress and woocommerce as a backend and bootstrap 4 and some addons to makke its frontend.

My code is ok. I have my navbar working fine and integrated. woocommerce fully themed (my own theme). My badge to shows up how many products is in cart. And this is also included in the navbar.

What I couldn't figure out how to, is to put this badge over my cart icon as you can see below:

[image]

I realised that when I put the code in wordpress>Menus, it didin't works.

Anybody could help me out?

front-page.php

```
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.quickgames.com.br">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/logo.png" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
  </a>

     <?php
     wp_nav_menu([
       'menu'            => 'top',
       'theme_location'  => 'top',
       'container'       => 'div',
       'container_id'    => 'bs4navbar',
       'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
       'menu_id'         => false,
       'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
       'depth'           => 2,
       'fallback_cb'     => 'bs4navwalker::fallback',
       'walker'          => new bs4navwalker()
     ]);
     ?>

    <!-- code for the badge START-->
    <div style="align:left">
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning"><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?></span>
    </div>
    <!-- code for the badge END-->

    <form class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Procurar Produtos...">
      <span class="input_group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-navbar" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      </span>
    </form>

   </nav>
```

Comment: try to put `a` tag and `span` tag inside same div

Comment: @mxr7350 it didn't work. Tks. All the stuffs changed the position, really mass :)

Comment: Thinking just with html and css, it is very simple to do (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25964085/how-to-make-bootstrap-navbar-dropdown-with-list-item-badges-aligned-to-the-right) but my content is generated by wordpress, and when I tryed to put the code there, wordpress can't read properly and the content didn't appear.